# Access iteration variable in passthrough attribute?

Tags: jsf, datatable, jsf-2.2

I'm wondering why I get a `NullPointerException` on the following:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{testBean.entities}" var="d">
  <h:column p:data-order="#{d.modifiedOn}">
    <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{d.modifiedOn}">
      <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{msg.datePattern}" />
    </h:outputText>
  </h:column>    
</h:dataTable>
```

Where the `p` namespace is `xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"`, `modifiedOn` is a (non-null) `Date` field.

The exception looks like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.getAttributeValue(HtmlResponseWriter.java:1211)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.flushAttributes(HtmlResponseWriter.java:1171)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.closeStartIfNecessary(HtmlResponseWriter.java:1113)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.writeText(HtmlResponseWriter.java:936)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:240)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.renderHeader(TableRenderer.java:339)
```

However, use of `#{d.modifiedOn}` is fine in any non-passthrough attributes like `headerClass`. As is any value not referencing the iteration variable in a passthrough attribute.

My question is: is this intended?

This is using Wildfly-8.0.0.Final's JSF implementation, version 2.2.5-jbossorg-3.

In case anyone's wondering: I'm trying to support [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) orthogonal data attributes to enhance my tables.

**Edited to add:** I've also tried, but got the same Exception, with adding the following to the `<h:column>`:

```
<f:passThroughAttribute name="data-order" value="#{d.modifiedOn}" />
```

This is apparently caused by JSF trying to render this attribute on the header where `rowIndex` is `-1` and iteration data is not yet present. So there's an hack solution to my specific problem:

```
<h:column p:data-order="#{empty d or empty d.modifiedOn ? '' : d.modifiedOn.time}">
  ...
</h:column>
```

Which still renders an empty/useless `data-order` attribute into my `thead`.

**Further testing:**
More testing has confirmed my suspicion that this only occurs with a `<f:facet name="header">` on *any* column (doesn't have to be the one with the attribute). Leaving those out defeats my goal of using the table as a base for datatables since that requires a well-formed table with a `<thead>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this intended? Definitelly it's not. Furthermore, here is the definition of a passthrough attribute according to the JSF 2.2 specification:

> **Pass Through Attributes**
>
> For any given JSF component tag in a view, the set of available attributes that component supports is determined by a 
>   combination of the UIComponentand Renderer for that tag. In some cases the value of the attribute is interpreted by 
>   the UIComponentor Renderer(for example, the columns attribute of h:panelGrid) and in others the value is 
>   passed straight through to the user agent (for example, the lang attribute of h:inputText).
>
> In both cases, the 
>   UIComponent/Renderer has a priori knowledge of the set of allowable attributes. Pass Through Attributes allows 
>   the view author to list arbitrary name value pairs that are passed straight through to the user agent without interpretation 
>   by the UIComponent/Renderer. This behavior is normatively specified in the “Rendering Pass Through Attributes” 
>   section of the overview of the standard HTML_BASIC render kit.

So the only functionality of that kind of attributes is to **notify the renderer that it must process the value for the attribute, but that it's not tied to any of the UIComponent features, so must end up at the final output**.

I have performed a test with Tomcat 7 + Mojarra 2.2.6 and it perfectly works for me. HTML  elements get rendered in the DOM tree with their *data-order* attribute, with the given date. That's the test case I've used:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.entities}" var="entity">
        <h:column p:data-order="#{entity.modifiedOn}">
            #{entity.name}
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:messages />
</h:body>
</html>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    public class Entity {
        private String name;

        private Date modifiedOn;

        public Entity(String name, Date modifiedOn) {
            this.name = name;
            this.modifiedOn = modifiedOn;
        }

        public Date getModifiedOn() {
            return modifiedOn;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create a List of entities with dates differing from now to now + 2 days
     */
    public List<Entity> entities = Arrays.asList(
            new Entity("name1", new Date()), new Entity("name2", new Date(
                    new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))), new Entity(
                    "name0", new Date(new Date().getTime()
                            + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 48))));

    public List<Entity> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

}
```

This means it's a bug in your JSF implementation (implementation which I didn't know about BTW). Your best is opening a bug track unless the authors have already fixed it in a later version.

**Edit**

The rendering fails with the given error when there's an `f:facet` for header or footer involved for the datatable. Apparently, Mojarra tries to evaluate the passthrough value for the facet before building the iterator, that causes it to fail as the variable is not yet available. Opened an [issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3208).

**See also:**

- [JSF 2.2 specification](https://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr344/index.html)

Comment: I'll switch in Mojarra-2.2.6 and test again. Also, I only hinted at that in my original post, but can you try with a `<f:facet name="header">` for the `<h:column>` to force generation of a table header?

Comment: With the header facet it throws the given exception also in Mojarra. I infer the reason for failing is: The passthrough attribute is being set in `<td>` elements, but when adding a column header, the header hasn't got a `<td>`, but a `<th>`. The framework however looks for a `<td>` and as it's not being found, an exception is thrown. I consider it to be a bug, so I'll open an issue report at Mojarra site.

Comment: Thanks, while I agree that this is at least unexpected, I think that the problem is actually the renderer trying to evaluate the expression too early: I interpret [h:dataTable VDL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html) as implying order and encoding the header is done before the `rowIndex` is set (only happens while rendering the table body), which will cause the iteration variable to be not accessible. So yeah, that might actually spec-compliant behavior. While failing on it with NPE is certainly.. unexpected.

Comment: Your "hack" works when `f:facet` is involved. That means what you say, the header encoding is performed too early for the EL expression to be evaluated. Apparently, Mojarra evaluates the header firstly and later on creates a full iterator which constructs each of the rows. The problem is the expression on the passthrough is not yet available when header rendering, just because the iteration variable hasn't been defined yet. That would cause the problem.

Comment: Jup, agrees with my reasoning. But I'm unsure about whether the spec people can do something it (Section 4.2.1.1 (DataModel properties) explicitly says `rowData` is `null` when not iterating). Would be nice if there's a solution, tho.